# How to create bread crumb using Menu items in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two XMl files. One is for top navigation menu and other for left navigation menu.Based on the top navigation the left hand menu gets changed .It works fine but i am having problem to create bread crumb using these two xml files. Any suggestion on how to create bread crumb for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to following Links. Preferably use siteMapProvider control

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicsitemap.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DynamicSitemapASPNET2.aspx

The other way is if you can do a lot of client side coding. When ever a navigation is done, you just have to create a new an anchor tag. The value of that anchor tag would be the page from which navigation was done. Could be easily done with Ajax.
for eg.
At page 1. Anchor tag would be `<a href="#">Page1</a>`
from page 1 to page 2. `<a href="\page1">Page1</a><a href="#">page 2</a>`

On top of it, you could give some fancy animations using JQuery

Comment: i am not using the sitemap xml file.Using XMl file which is automatically generated from Ekton CMS work area.